# control multiple buttons with one swipe gesture swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, ontouch

I have array of `UIImageView` that printed on the main View (as subviews) in a matrix.

That `UIImageViews` interact while I am tap on them (work like a pixel when I touch one of them it turn on (move from black to green)

but I want to do it with swipe gesture so i can with one swipe trigger more than one "pixel" (UIImageView)

I found this for android [triggering-multiple-buttonsonclick-event-with-one-swipe-gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500318/triggering-multiple-buttonsonclick-event-with-one-swipe-gesture) 
and I wonder if there is something like that in ios with swift that recognise general touch (not tap or swipe) so I can looks for it.

The main purpose of all of this is to draw "shapes" on matrix of pixels with one swipe gestures.

If there is another way that you think will help I will be happy to here about it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i Manage to do the the swipe action using touchesMoved and touchesEnded

while the main idea is to invoke the UIIMageViews using the Coordinate of the touch and compare it to the to the UIImageViews Coordinates in the touchesMoved function

using flags to disable already edited UIIMageViews (while i am in the same touch session , the finger still on the screen) and refresh the UIImageViews to be editable again in the touchesEnded

```
    func swipeTouches(touches: NSSet!) {
            // Get the first touch and its location in this view controller's view coordinate system
            let touch = touches.allObjects[0] as! UITouch
            let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self.view)

            for pixel in pixelArrays {
                // Convert the location of the obstacle view to this view controller's view coordinate system
                let pixelViewFrame = self.view.convertRect(pixel.pixelImage.frame, fromView: pixel.pixelImage.superview)

                // Check if the touch is inside the obstacle view
                if CGRectContainsPoint(pixelViewFrame, touchLocation) {
                    // check if the pixel is Editable
                    if(!pixel.isEditable){
                        let index = pixel.index
                        pixelArrays.insert(updatePixel(index) , atIndex: index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

the only problem that i have now that if the swipe begin on one of the UIImageViews the touchesMoved function consider it the the view to looks for the coordinate and the other UIImageViews are not effected

my idea to solve it is to add layer on top all of the UIImageViews and disable the tap recognition that they alredy have and implement the tap also with the Coordinates way.

i will be happy to hear if there is another way to do it

***Update :
i mange to solve the problem above by sort of what i wrote but instead of add another layer i disable the touch on all of the UIImageViews and invoke them using the Coordinates of the touch and them***

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `UIGestureRecognizer`.
With this you can add many types of gestures, as swipe, touch..etc.

You can also get position, duration, and basically all the information about it.

You can check step by step tutorial in this link.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

And also in the apple documentation.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/