# Sliding over buttons

Tags: android, button, slide

I want to be able to 'slide' over my buttons and perform like they were each clicked when touched. (Act on 0, not on 1). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

button.setOnTouchListener would do the trick

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                //Insert desired code here
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Could you explain what you mean by "slide over these buttons and make them react in a row"?

Comment: I mean, I would like to activate another button without releasing finger from the previous click
Thanks for reply :)

Comment: You mean multitouch?

Comment: No, I mean using one finger to trigger many buttons without releasing it.

Comment: So you mean like dragging your finger through buttons and triggering them, something like mobile pattern pascode, where you drag the finger through the circles to unlock your phone?

Comment: Indeed, also it could be a line, which must be slided on continuosly to work. I mean you stop swiping, action stops.

Comment: Maybe these links could help you: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500318/triggering-multiple-buttonsonclick-event-with-one-swipe-gesture
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872464/get-button-coordinates-and-detect-if-finger-is-over-them-android